# Can Korra now go into the avatar state when ever she wants?

Tags: the-legend-of-korra

I'm confused, it's said that you have to open all of your chi's to enter the avatar state on your own, but did Korra open them all?

Answer (score 5):

**Yes, she should be able to achieve the Avatar state now that she can achieve communion with the previous Avatar spirits.**

- She did open all of the gates within her once she was able to release herself at the lowest point of her emotional turmoil.

> Korra was surprised to see Aang, who told her that she finally connected with her spiritual self. When Korra asked how, Aang told her, "When we hit our lowest point, we are open to the greatest change". All of the previous incarnations of the Avatar appeared behind Aang and he then used energybending to restore Korra's bending. As her past lives faded away, Korra entered the Avatar State and bent all four elements for the first time. [**-- Avatar Wiki > Korra**](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Korra)

- This does not mean it will be easy for her to achieve it. Likely the state will require her to remain focused, grounded and in spiritual connection with the spiritual realm.

> Six months after defeating Amon and gaining access to the Avatar State, Korra was seen at Air Temple Island with Jinora, Ikki and Meelo having an air scooter race. After a close race, Korra used the Avatar State as a boost to win. Tenzin quickly castigated Korra about using the Avatar State for her own entertainment. Korra, however, seemed uninterested in the conversation. She was later seen at the Southern Water Tribe during a festival trying to calm Naga, who was howling after seeing a strange figure, which was discovered to be a malevolent spirit. Korra fought the spirit by entering the Avatar State. [**-- Avatar Wiki > Korra**](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Korra)

Comment: Could you please update your answer. It is out of date as Korra can no longer enter the avatar state at will as of Book Two, Spirits. :)

Comment: Please treat SE sites more like Wikipedia and less like a messageboard.  Updating your answer is VERY appropriate as new knowledge comes into play.

Comment: I can agree there could be some development of answers but I question how often articles can be updated once you get a few hundred answers (or in my case a few thousand)? New knowledge comes into play all the time. I was under the impression we were not necessarily trying to be Wikipedia, instead answering specific questions as they arose. I guess I could be wrong... I will make updates as my time allows.